# Find some Hardware Details in .net

Tags: .net, hardware

I make program to find any hardware in PC and I use `System.Management`. Now in some hardware i found problem, for example with VGA or sound card on board, found it but these are properties of the mother board. Or it cant found monitor right. Is there any library or something else to find them?

Comment: Yes, the sound card or graphics card is often built into the motherboard. I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: You can use directx for graphic card information.

Comment: One way to know they are on board.

Comment: thank @CodyGray for edit this. for first example i say this can't find difference between on board VGA and VGA which one is on PCI express slot. I say it's not perfect is there any way to found them true?

Answer (score 0):

> I make program to find any hardware in PC and I use System.Management. Now in some hardware i 
>   found problem, for example with VGA or sound card on board, found it but these are properties of 
>   the mother board.

So waht is the problem? This sounds all correct to me.

> Or it cant found monitor right

Taht is because there are still a lot of STUPID monitors. I.e. not smart enough to properly communicate with the computer so the computer just knows "generic monitor".

> Is there any library or something else to found them true?

No. But on another question - what the heck in this question is C# specific?

Comment: It is not C# specific, but it he is probably looking for a way to achieve it in C# (hence System.Management).

Comment: Irrelevant. THis is like asking "what is a good pizza shop, I use a ford focus to drive there".

Comment: People often use the C# tag to indicate that they want you to write the code for them, and they wish for it to be written in C#.

Comment: People are also often clueless about what they do. I dotn really care. It is not a langauge specific question. Arguing about common sense when a significant part of the population lacks it is not sensible either. I corrected the tagging.

Comment: @TomTom to answer your question: "Is there any library or something else to find them?", "something else" would be C# code that the OP hasn't thought of.

Comment: excuse me @tom tom I asked `Is there any library or something else to found them true?`, above this question i wrote some detail to found the problem if you know that. every body like you see programs to get hardware with true details, like _PCWizard_ or some else. and in these programs found monitor right. Now is there any way to get true detail from PC for all hardwares.

Comment: But all this is .NET related or something, NONE is related to the C# language.

Comment: you are irrational, okay no relation between this question and C#. Do you have any right answer to this?